Jetpack Compose Canvas adaptive Pinch to zoom effect problem
I'm trying to add zoom in/out using Pinch effect (code below), however, the problem is the code works almost fine when the pinch center is close to zero (of the canvas), but when it goes far away from the zero everything goes wrong the drawings disappeared, the drawing data is within the range of 1e-15 to 1e15, here the code:
class CanvasActivity : ComponentActivity() {
  val vm: MainCanvasViewModel by viewModels<MainCanvasViewModel>()
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
      CanvasAppTheme {
        AppCanvasView2(vm)
      }
    }
  }
...


@Composable
fun AppCanvasView2(vm: MainCanvasViewModel) {

  var scale by remember { mutableStateOf(1f) }
  var translate by remember { mutableStateOf(Offset.Zero) }

  Box(
    contentAlignment = Alignment.TopStart,
    modifier = Modifier
      .background(canvasBackgroundColor)
      .fillMaxSize()
  ) {
    Canvas(
      Modifier
      .align(Alignment.TopStart)
      .pointerInput(Unit){
        detectTransformGestures { gestureCentroid, gesturePan, gestureZoom, _ ->
          if (gestureZoom == 1f /* no zoom */){  // handle Pan only
            translate += gesturePan * gestureZoom // works fine

          }else{ // handle zoom only
            val oldScale = scale
            scale *= gestureZoom
            // calc dx, dy due to the change of the scale
            val scaleChange = oldScale / scale
            val dx_byZoom = (gestureCentroid.x * gestureZoom - translate.x) * (scaleChange -1)
            val dy_byZoom = (gestureCentroid.y * gestureZoom - translate.y) * (scaleChange -1)
            
            translate += Offset(dx_byZoom, dy_byZoom)
          }
        }
      }
      .graphicsLayer(
        scaleX = scale,
        scaleY = scale,
        translationX = translate.x,
        translationY = translate.y,
        transformOrigin = TransformOrigin(0f, 0f),
      )
      .fillMaxSize()
    ) {
      // some drawings ...
    }


  } /** End of Box */

} /** End of [AppCanvasView2] */

thanks in advance, any help will be appreciated.

everything goes wrong Can you edit your post and further explain what you mean by that?
